# TOF Sensor add timer to turn off LED

Tags: c++, arduino

I have a time of flight sensor that will measure the distance between my car and the wall in the garage. I have them hooked up with some red LEDs. If the **distance** is less than or equal to 50mm, then the LEDs turn on. But I don't want the LEDs to stay on all night, so I tried to write logic to create a timer or something to turn off the LEDs despite the fact that my car will still trigger the **distance** threshold of 50mm.I know it's a bit confusing because the 50mm threshold will trigger the LEDs to turn on when an object is <= 50mm. So, what I want is something to trigger the LEDs off after x amount of seconds.

This is my Arduino code:

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <VL53L0X.h>
#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>

VL53L0X sensor;

Adafruit_NeoPixel strip = Adafruit_NeoPixel(8, 8, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);

// Time calculation
unsigned long startTime;
unsigned long endTime;    // store end time here
unsigned long duration;   // duration stored
byte timerRunning;

void setup()
{
  strip.begin();
  strip.show();

  pinMode(12, INPUT_PULLUP);
  digitalWrite(12, HIGH); 

  Serial.begin(9600);
  Wire.begin();
  sensor.init();
  sensor.setTimeout(500);

  sensor.startContinuous();
}

void loop()
{
  delay(1000); 
  int tofdata = sensor.readRangeContinuousMillimeters();
  int distance = tofdata;
  Serial.print( distance );
  Serial.println( " mm" );

  if(sensor.timeoutOccurred()){Serial.print("TIMEOUT");}
  
  if ( timerRunning == 0 && distance <= 50 ){
      startTime = millis() / 1000; 
      Serial.println("time started, starting count");
      timerRunning = 1;   
      colorWipe(strip.Color(255, 0, 0), 50);

  }

  // Turn off LED if it's 5 seconds or more
  if(duration >= 5000){
      endTime = millis() / 1000;
      timerRunning = 0; 
      duration =  endTime - startTime;
      colorWipe(strip.Color(0, 0, 0), 50);
  }
 
  if ( timerRunning == 1 && distance >= 50 ){
      endTime = millis() / 1000;
      timerRunning = 0; 
      duration =  endTime - startTime; 
      Serial.println ("Presence detected for seconds: ");
      Serial.print(duration);
      colorWipe(strip.Color(0, 0, 0), 50);
  }

}
// Fill the dots one after the other with a color
void colorWipe(uint32_t c, int wait) {
  for(int i=0; i < strip.numPixels(); i++) {
    strip.setPixelColor(i, c);
    strip.show();
    //delay(wait);
  }
}
```

If you guys can help me or point me at the right direction, I'd appreciate that. Thanks!

UPDATE: I updated my code BUT I still can't figure this out!

Also, when I think it works, it doesn't, the LED lights just flicker repeatedly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I came back to this project a few days ago tinkering with it until I finally figured out a solution to my TOF sensor and LED problem. I modified my code a bit to get it working for my application.

**nothing different here just basic includes**

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <VL53L0X.h>
#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>
```

**here I decided to create a variable for LED pin and Number of LEDS**

```
#define PIN 8
#define NUM_LEDS 60
```

**here I created a variable to store the start time when the LEDS are on**

```
unsigned long startTime = 0;
```

**this code sets a max time for the LEDS to be on, in this case, 15 seconds**

```
const unsigned long LED_Lights_Max_Time_On = 15000;
```

**here I'm setting a boolean flag to keep track when the LEDS are on**

```
bool led_on = false;
```

**this here is what made my application work. I'm setting a max distance limit. In this case is 150mm. Before I had set as 50mm, but I decided to change it. Just a side note there.**

```
int max_distance_limit = 150;
```

**nothing new here just adding TOF and LED strip and standard setup code block**

```
VL53L0X sensor;

Adafruit_NeoPixel strip = Adafruit_NeoPixel(NUM_LEDS, PIN, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);

void setup()
{
  strip.begin();
  strip.show();
  
  pinMode(12, INPUT_PULLUP);
  digitalWrite(12, HIGH); 

  Serial.begin(9600);
  Wire.begin();
  sensor.init();
  sensor.setTimeout(500);

  sensor.startContinuous();
}
```

**here is where the real fun begins. In this if statement I'm comparing the distance with the max_distance_limit variable and making sure that the led_on flag is set to false. If both of them are true, then start the timer, turn the led_on flag to true, and turn the LED strip on to color red.**

```
int distance = sensor.readRangeContinuousMillimeters();
if (distance <= max_distance_limit && led_on == false ){
      startTime = millis();  //initial start time
      led_on = true;
      colorWipe(strip.Color(255, 0, 0), 50);
  }
```

**this other check just does the opposite from the above first check. It turns off the LEDs based on the condition.**

```
if(distance >=max_distance_limit && led_on == true){
      colorWipe(strip.Color(0, 0, 0), 50);
      led_on = false;
  }
```

**here I created two functions that will check the status of the LEDs. I'll explain both in detail on the actual function setup**

```
checkLEDLightStatus(distance);
changeMaxDistanceLimit(distance);
```

**this just turns the LEDs on. simple function**

```
void colorWipe(uint32_t c, int wait) {
  for(int i=0; i < strip.numPixels(); i++) {
    strip.setPixelColor(i, c);
    strip.show();
    //delay(wait);
  }
}
```

**in this function I'm passing 1 parameter then I added a check to see if the led_on flag is set to true, then check to see if the time elapsed 15 seconds, and compare the distance to the max distance limit variable. If all those 3 are true, then turn the LEDs off, update the led_on flag to false, update the max_distance_limit equal to 4. This code makes the LED's turn off because I'm changing the max_distance_limit to 4 instead of <=150**

```
void checkLEDLightStatus(int distance)
{
 
  if(led_on == true && millis() - startTime > LED_Lights_Max_Time_On && distance <= max_distance_limit){
    colorWipe(strip.Color(0, 0, 0), 50);
    led_on = false;
    max_distance_limit = 4;
  }  
}
```

**in this function I'm passing the distance variable again because since the TOF sensor is still active, I can update the max_distance_limit back to 150 if the distance reads greater than or equal to 151**

```
void changeMaxDistanceLimit(int distance)
{
  if(led_on == false && distance >= 151){
    max_distance_limit = 150;
  }
}
```

I know that there's more ways and perhaps a better way to go about this solution, but as I mentioned earlier, it works perfectly fine for my application. I'm always open to other solutions and suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You`re on the right track.

You store a time stamp when you turn on the LEDs. But your problem is that you reset this every time loop is executed.

The condition to turn off the leds after 10 seconds would be `millis() > milliseconds + time`

You should not reset the start time when the leds are off. Which leasds to the following conditions:

If the leds are off and distance gets <= 50 you turn on the leds and store a turn-on-time.
If the led is on and the current time exceeds the turn-on-time plus the desired on-delay or if the distance becomes > 50 you turn the led off.

You may think of more complex states. For example you could start the timer only if the car has stopped and turn them back on when the car starts moving.

Comment: thank you so much for responding. So, put the logic on void setup() method instead of void loop() method?

Comment: no setup is only for stuff that needs to be executed once befor you enter the main loop. that loop runs forever checking conditions and doing stuff depending on them. (google state machine).  the loop ensures that those conditions are checked continuously. if any of those conditions is true you do something.  so if the led is on and the time is over you turn the led off. if the distance is too small (and doesn't change) and the led is off, you turn it on and note the start time.  these two conditions are exclusive. they cannot be true at the same time.

Comment: you just need a if else if statement inside loop. just think what you would do and check if you were sitting there with your watch, a switch and a tape measure. you would continously measure, asking yourself if it is close enough to flip the switch...  google rubberducking

Comment: thank you so much for this awesome info. I'm going to google state machine which it might be what I need here.